# cake bake not finding database.php on linux mint

Tags: php, linux, cakephp

I've been using `cakephp` on windows for a couple of years now with no problems but I decided to switch to mint linux recently and there seems to be a lot more set up!

So I set up my `xampp` and copied one of my projects over from my old system. I `755 chmod`'d the whole `cakephp` application and `777` the `app/tmp` directory in particular.

Everything works fine in the browser.

But when I go to the console (which I had to install separately - never had to do this with windows?) and `cd` to the app folder and type '`cake bake all`', it tells me:

> 'PHP warning: include_once(etc/etc/config/database.php)' ... 'failed to open stream'

and so on.

The file definitely exists and if the exact same codes where on my windows machine this would normally work for me.

Is there something else I need to do? Google and looking on here turned up nothing so far :(

Comment: Using xampp on linux is your first mistake. Use LAMP packages provided by your distro and it will make your environment config much smoother.

Comment: Do you really have an `etc/etc/config/` directory? Where did you setup that?